# issue uploading image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was following a tutorial on how to do so;
I created a separate table for the user's profile model;

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('profile_image')->nullable();//profile image
            $table->string('address')->unique();
            $table->string('phoneno')->unique();
            $table->string('sex');
            $table->string('martial_status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

then i copied this file `UploadTrait.php` in the Traits folder but the code didn't highlight in my vs code editor

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

trait UploadTrait
{
    public function uploadOne(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folder = null, $disk = 'public', $filename = null)
    {
        $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : Str::random(25);

        $file = $uploadedFile->storeAs($folder, $name.'.'.$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension(), $disk);

        return $file;
    }
}
```

Here is my **Profilescontroller**

```
 public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        // Form validation
        $request->validate([
            'profile_image'    => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2040',
            'address'          => 'required',
            'phoneno'          => 'required',
            'sex'              => 'required',
            'martial_status'   => 'required'
        ]);

        // Get current user
        $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
        // Set user name
        $user->accno = $request->input('accno');

        //check if a profile image has been uploaded
        if ($request->has('profile_image')) {
            // Get image file
            $image = $request->file('profile_image');
            // Make a image name based on user name and current timestamp
            $name = Str::slug($request->input('accno')).'_'.time();
            // Define folder path
            $folder = '/uploads/images/';
            // Make a file path where image will be stored [ folder path + file name + file extension]
            $filePath = $folder.$name. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Upload image
            $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public' , $name);
            // Set user profile image path in database to filePath
            $user->profile()->profile_image = $filePath;
        }
        // Persist user record to database
        $user->save();

        // Return user back and show a flash message
        return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => 'Profile updated successfully.']);
    }
```

I get this error when I finally load the page

> BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::uploadOne does not exist.

even though i refer to `uploadOne()` in **UploadTrait.php**, I need help to understand where i went wrong.

Comment: use UploadTrait; ?

Comment: Did you include use App\Traits\UploadTrait; in your controller?

Comment: yes it's working now but i'm getting  a 419 page expired error

Answer (score 1):

In your ProfileController Class make sure that you are using the UploadTrait

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\UploadTrait; /// Add the Path to your UploadTrait.
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    use UploadTrait;  /// After the class is declared add this statement to use the trait

    ...

     public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: yes the error stop after i added the path to the UploadTrait but it's showing me a 419 page expired error

Comment: That's actually a separate issue, the form is missing the csrf token, check the docs as it depends on if you are using blade templates, VueJs or another framework for your UI [Laravel Docs - CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf)